# how to import stock split data form yahoo finance by using python?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I tried with yahoo-action in data reader but it only gives the dividend values as follows.

code-

```
import pandas_datareader as web
web.DataReader('VOLTAS.NS','yahoo-actions')
```

output-

```
action  value
2019-04-30  DIVIDEND    4.8
2019-04-29  DIVIDEND    4.8
2019-04-26  DIVIDEND    4.8
2018-05-02  DIVIDEND    4.4
2018-04-27  DIVIDEND    4.4
```

I want the same thing but with the splits